# Was ist der Plural von "Forst"

Tags: grammatical-number

Die Verwaltung des landeseigenen Waldes in Bayern unterliegt einem Unternehmen, das sich

> Bayerische Staatsforsten

nennt. Die Pluralbildung *Forsten* ist mir an sich nicht geläufig - Ich kenne das als *Forste*, Grimm ist mit mir einig und bietet noch das (damals schon) veraltete "Förste" an. DWDS und Canoo kennen beide Pluralbildungen, Wikipedia verwendet nur *Forste*, der Online-Duden hält sich raus. Eine [ngrams-Suche](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=forsten%2Cforste&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cforsten%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cforste%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cforsten%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cforste%3B%2Cc0) findet sehr viele deklinierte Substantive und ist wohl nicht sehr sinnvoll.

Der Plural ist bei diesem Wort natürlich rar - Ist das ein ursprünglich bairischer Regionalismus? Oder ist das eine "von Amts wegen" gerne verwendete Pluralbildung (Ämter verwenden "Forst" natürlich öfter im Plural).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Online-Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Forst) (unter "Grammatik") und [WDG](https://www.dwds.de/wb/wdg/Forst) (daher hat DWDS wohl seinen Plural) lassen – ohne weiteren Kommentar – sowohl *Forste* als auch *Forsten* zu.

Die *Frühneuhochdeutsche Grammatik* von Ebert/Reichmann/Solms/Wegera behandelt *Forst* unter § M 11. Dort geht es um Maskulina, die *-(e)n*-Plural angenommen haben. Bei *Forst* und *Mast* existieren anscheinend die historisch älteren starken Formen auf *-e* und die jüngeren schwachen auf *-en* ohne Bedeutungsunterschied nebeneinander. Bei anderen Wörtern kam es, wie bei dem berühmten Fall *Worte* vs. *Wörter*, zu einer Bedeutungsdifferenzierung. Neben dem Plural *Zinsen* soll es regional *Zinse* in der Bedeutung *Mietzins* geben; neben *Dornen* fachsprachlich den Plural *Dorne* für ein Werkzeug. Bei einigen Wörtern sind die schwachen Pluralformen wieder aufgegeben worden *(Stiefel)*; bei anderen haben die schwachen Formen die starken ersetzt *(Helden)*.<sup>[1](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Zins) [2](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Dorn) [3](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?lemma=stiefel) [4](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?lemma=held)</sup>

Bei *Forsten* spricht zunächst einmal nichts für eine bayerisch-regionale Deutung. Das Bundesministerium für Ernährung und Landwirtschaft hieß bis 2001 Bundesministerium für Ernährung, Landwirtschaft und Forsten ([BMEL](https://www.bmel.de/DE/Ministerium/_Texte/Geschichteseit1949.html)) und in Schleswig-Holstein, Niedersachsen und Rheinland-Pfalz gibt es, entsprechend den bayerischen Staatsforsten, Landesforsten.

(*Landesforsten* verbindet sich mit *die, der, den*, ist also klar Plural und nicht  Neutrum Singular. Wenn daran irgendwelche Zweifel bestanden haben sollten.)

Comment: "Forsten" könnte aber auch ein substantivierter Infinitiv (sagt man das so?) sein, wie aufforsten, dass Aufforsten. Allerdings hieß es ja nicht "Ernähren, Landwirtschaften und Forsten".

Comment: @userunknown Um ehrlich zu sein, das ist genau das, was ich bisher immer geglaubt hatte...

Comment: @unser unknown.  Man denke auch an das *Ministerium für Abschrecken und Töten*